Changing html font height element without changing its width using css
I am making a website where the user can set a font height and width in pixels, and I have started by trying to change the height of a font without modifying its width.
Ideally I want to be able to do something like font-height: 20px; and be able to set the height in pixel to be more precise in the dimension of the fonts.
I have seen it is possible to change the height of a font using transform: scaleY(1.5); in css, however I couldn't be precise using this method, especially since the font-width in my website would be dynamic as well.
Is this possible ?

You'd probably have more luck with the transform approach in the suggested duplicate, but if you really want to use font-size, you could try and do some scaling yourself using font-stretch (MDN Docs)

Please visit [ask]
